# how can I got stripe confirmation after successfully paid a payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to console after getting my payment but it doesn't work.

```
    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
     elements,
     confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: "/dashBoard/myorder",
     },
  },
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 1):

From the Stripe.js [website](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment?type=pii):

```
stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the PaymentIntent is confirmed.
    return_url: 'https://example.com',
  },
})
.then(function(result) {
  if (result.paymentIntent) {

  }
});
```